# Java - No Main Manifest Attribute, in App.jar error even though MANIFEST.MF file is in /META-INF

Tags: java, jar

I have been trying to get this to work, but it won't. I went through the Archive Manager and found the `MANIFEST.MF` file in `App.jar/META-INF/` so I don't know why it says there isn't one!

`chmod`-ing it with `chmod +x ./App.jar` and running `./App.jar` returns

```
bash: ./App.jar: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Running Linux Mint 20 (Based on Ubuntu 20.04) With OpenJDK 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java -jar App.jar` to run the executable JAR file.

There is a way to make JAR files directly executable using the `binfmt_misc` kernel feature but most users/linux distributions don't bother to set it up.